# shouldStartLoadWithRequest not working when I click on UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have implemented `UIWebView` with HTML content.

```
UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:subView.frame];
webView.delegate=self;
webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[webView addSubview:chartWebView];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

When the webview is loading delegate methods, it's working fine, but when I click on a link, the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method is not called.

I wrote methods like below:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{   
  if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"ios:"])
  {
      [self performSelector:@selector(getValuesFromWebToNative)];

      return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Delegate for both `webView` and `chartWebView` then try, that `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` function will call when link pressed

Answer (score -1):

The webView has a subView `chartWebView`. If the link is in the `chartWebView`, the delegate method may not be called. I can't get enough details from your code. You can post more details.